# Issues translating 16-bit Int (NetCDF) to GeoTIFF with gdal_translate

Tags: geotiff-tiff, netcdf, gdal-translate

I am attempting to translate the .nc dataset to GeoTIFF but run into issues with the colors of the final TIFF file. It is a 1-band dataset (lat, lon, temperature (K).

Command I am using:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff LIIN50_202002060900.nc whydoesntthiswork.tiff
```

This runs without complaint, but the TIFF produced appears over saturated. ie. the values where temperature is higher are far to bright. This is compared to a plot of the NetCDF in Python.

Comment: Does it work better with `-ot Int16`? Make sure you inspect actual pixel values, visuals are misleading and your GIS might use a different color scale each time if you are unlucky.

Comment: I've tried with all -ot options, no improvement :(

Comment: Did you investigate actual pixel values like I said?

Comment: Hi yes, it seems like something is off with the pixel values range - my data range from 200 - 290 Kelvin but the High/Low for pixel values is -32045 and 32568. The colour scale is also inverted. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Those values might be misleading and depend on the software you use to gather them. Have you compared actual pixel values of specific pixels/rastercells?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Either https://gdal.org/programs/gdallocationinfo.html or something like QGIS :)